# Casting to Less Derived Types and Dealing with Generics

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to write something capable of taking various behavior classes and linking them together into a chain of queries and commands.  One approach I've taken is below, but I'm running into an issue casting derived types to base types.  I'm having to deal with generic parameters, and I'm not sure if this approach isn't possible, or if I need to define some implicit or explicit conversion operators, or something else altogether.

Here is the set of base types.  First is the most basic interface:

```
public interface IInvoker
{
    void Invoke();
}
```

This abstract class adds the ability to have a "subject" which is the thing that does the command or query via one of its members.  It defers implementing the Invoke method:

```
public abstract class AbstractInvoker<TSubject> : IInvoker
{
    protected TSubject Subject;

    public void SetSubject(TSubject subject)
    {
        Subject = subject;
    }

    public abstract void Invoke();
}
```

This next abstract class would be the type implemented by any concrete query class (as opposed to a command, which would not have a TResult type).  It sets up the ability to chain queries via the Successor.

```
public abstract class AbstractQueryInvoker<TSubject, TResult> : AbstractInvoker<TSubject>
{
    protected AbstractInvoker<TResult> Successor;

    public void SetSuccessor(AbstractInvoker<TResult> successor)
    {
        Successor = successor;
    }

    public override void Invoke()
    {
        var result = DoQuery();

        Successor.SetSubject(result);
        Successor.Invoke();
    }

    protected abstract TResult DoQuery();
}
```

The actual query logic is implemented in concrete classes via the `DoQuery()` method.

I set it up like this so I could chain the queries together like this:

```
private List<IInvoker> _invokers;

// Build the list of various concrete classes

for (int i = 0; i < _invokers.Count - 1; i++)
{
    ((AbstractQueryInvoker<dynamic, dynamic>)_invokers[i]).SetSuccessor(
                                                                        (AbstractInvoker<dynamic>)
                                                                        _invokers[i + 1]);
}
```

My aim was to have each invoker, except for the last one, have its successor chained up here so all I would need to do would be to call `Invoke()` on the first element.  However, the first cast in the for loop isn't working (and the second might not either, I'm guessing).  The error message looks something like this:

```
{"Unable to cast object of type 'ConcreteQueryInvoker' to type 'AbstractQueryInvoker`2[System.Object,System.Object]'."}
```

I'm hoping there is some way to get around this without having to implement something particular in each concrete Invoker.  I may end up having dozens of these concrete classes, each using different types for the generic type parameters.  So, is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: The names in your example are not consistent. For example `IActionInvoker` is not shown anywhere. Please post real code that is compilable.

Comment: @JesseGood - Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast each invoker to `dynamic`:

```
// Build the list of various concrete classes
for (int i = 0; i < _invokers.Count - 1; i++)
{
    ((dynamic)_invokers[i]).SetSuccessor((dynamic)_invokers[i + 1]);
}
```

**Why your original code doesn't work:**
Although `AbstractQueryInvoker<dynamic, dynamic>` uses the `dynamic` keyword, it's not actually a dynamic type—only `dynamic` by itself is dynamic. At run time, the `dynamic` type arguments are substituted by `object`, and so the cast fails.

Comment: Interesting.  This works.  Are you saying it would have also worked if I had used object instead of dynamic?  In any case, thank you.

Comment: No, I was merely pointing out that the run-time exception mentions ``AbstractQueryInvoker`2[System.Object,System.Object]`` because `dynamic` was replaced by `object.`

Comment: I misinterpreted  you the first time.  Now that I read again, it's pretty obvious that using object instead of dynamic won't change the fact that casts to object fail!

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood what you're trying to do I think you've made your code a little complicated and possibly fragile.

Tell me if something like this is better for you:

```
IInvoker<string> invoker =
    5
        .CreateBehaviour()
        .AddBehaviour(n => n * 2)
        .AddBehaviour(n => n + 1)
        .AddBehaviour(n => n.ToString())
        .AddBehaviour(n => n + "!");

Console.WriteLine(invoker.Invoke());
```

That outputs `"11!"` after running each step.

The code to do it is this:

```
public static class BehaviorsEx
{
    private class Subject<TSubject> : IInvoker<TSubject, TSubject>
    {
        private TSubject _subject;

        public Subject(TSubject subject)
        {
            _subject = subject;
        }

        public TSubject Invoke() { return _subject; }
    }

    private class Invoker<TSubject, TResult> : IInvoker<TSubject, TResult>
    {
        private IInvoker<TSubject> _inner;
        private Func<TSubject, TResult> _behaviour;

        public Invoker(IInvoker<TSubject> inner, Func<TSubject, TResult> behaviour)
        {
            _inner = inner;
            _behaviour = behaviour;
        }

        public TResult Invoke()
        {
            var x = _inner.Invoke();
            return _behaviour(x);
        }
    }

    public static IInvoker<TSubject> CreateBehaviour<TSubject>(this TSubject @this)
    {
        return new Subject<TSubject>(@this);
    }

    public static IInvoker<TResult> AddBehaviour<TSubject, TResult>(this IInvoker<TSubject> @this, Func<TSubject, TResult> behaviour)
    {
        return new Invoker<TSubject, TResult>(@this, behaviour);
    }
}

public interface IInvoker<TResult>
{
    TResult Invoke();
}

public interface IInvoker<TSubject, TResult> : IInvoker<TResult>
{
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I will try to play around with this today to see how it works, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I think this probably will not work for my situation, but I am going to see if a similar variation might, particularly with Func and Action. What I'm doing is essentially executing a macro. Definitions of each step the macro takes will be stored in a database. Each macro has one or more queries followed by a command. Every query has a subject, result and a successor. The successor is either another query or the final command. The final command does a void operation on the result of the string of queries. In effect the process looks like this:  (see next comment)

Comment: Query collection A for objects of type B, pass the result on to the next query...

Query collection B for objects of type C, pass it on...

Query C for D, pass it on...

Run a command on each element of D.

I forgot to mention that a command only has a subject.  It does not have a result or a successor.  However, to execute a chain of queries (with different type parameters) followed by a command, I needed a common Interface between them all, which is where IInvoker<TSubject> came in.  This way I can get the instruction records from the DB, assemble them in order and invoke the chain.

Comment: @bubbleking - Sounds good. I would suggest that next time you ask your question using this actual code rather than an abstraction. It would be easier for us to answer.

Comment: It's hard to figure out where to draw the line sometimes.  There is actually quite a bit more to it than what I've described, even.